Ground painting consider as grass not as mesh
i can't manage to use ground image from the asset store for painting terrain, i can only put it on the grass category so the image is vertical on the terrain, as in the picture in the link. I've try to delet and download it again but that didn't worked. Please help me. [enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/oTMP5HrA.png)
I've tried to change parameters, download other packs from the assets store, delet and download again unity, but nothing helped. That's weird because on my first tries that was working and without changing anything that wasn't working anymore.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Thank you, I don't really know what to add, I haven't written any code, just use the basic functions, download some assets from the store. I worked at the beginning, but after that the interface changed, and that didn't work anymore, but i didn't change the version or anything, and my previous project couldn't be changed like i wanted anymore. They had the same problem as the new ones. Please tell me what to provide to enlighten you.
